# apache flink doesnt connect to port 8081

Tags: server, localhost, apache-flink

Hi i am new to apache flink and i am trying to run a batch wordcount example to start learning about it.I have run
./bin/start-cluster.sh
and then i executed ./bin/flink run ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input test.txt --output out.txt
and i get the following
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081

[console messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHOYV.png)

so i think its about server connection error and i tried some things like xampp but nothing better
So what's your opinion on that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your cluster is not starting. Please try `./bin/start-cluster.sh` again and go to `http://localhost:8081/` to confirm your cluster is up. After that, the word count example should run fine after specifying the appropriate input and output files.